# Array organizing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, while-loop

I have python code below:

```
ht_24 = []
ht_23 = []
ht_22 = []
...

all_arr = [ht_24, ht_23, ht_22, ht_21, ht_20, ht_19, ht_18, ht_17, ht_16, ht_15, ht_14, ht_13, ht_12, ht_11, ht_10, ht_09, ht_08, ht_07, ht_06, ht_05, ht_04, ht_03, ht_02, ht_01]    

i = 0                                         
j = 0                                         
while i < 24:                                 
    while j < 24864:                          
        all_arr[i].append(read_matrix[j+i])   
        j += 24                               
        print(j)                              
    i += 1                                    
    print(i)
```

where read_matrix is an array of shape 24864, 17.

I want to read every 24th line from different starting indexs (0-24) and append them to the corresponding arrays for each line. Please help, this is so hard!

Comment: "array of shape 24864, 17." Are you sure it isn't 24864 by 24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to learn in Python:

ONE: **for** loops -- when you know ahead of time how many times you're going through the loop.  Your **while** loops above are both this type.  Try these instead:

```
for i in range(24):
    for j in range(0, 24864, 24):
        all_arr[i].append(read_matrix[j+i])
        print(j)
    print(i)
```

It's better when you let the language handle the index values for you.

TWO: **List comprehensions**: sort of a **for** loop inside a list construction.  Your entire posted code can turn into a single statement:

```
all_arr = [[read_matrix[j+i] \
                for j in range(0, 24864, 24) ] \
            for i in range(24) ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use a for loop originally!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think

```
list(zip(*zip(*[iter(read_matrix)]*24)))
```

may be what you're looking for.

```
list(zip(*zip(*[iter(range(24864))]*24)))[0][:5]
```

The above just looks at the indices, and the first few elements of the first sublist are

```
(0, 24, 48, 72, 96)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can `numpy` library do what you want?

```
import numpy as np
# 24864 row, 17 columns
read_matrix = np.arange(24864*17).reshape(24864,17)
new_matrices = [[] for i in range(24)] 

for i in range(24):
    # a has 17 columns
    a = read_matrix[slice(i,None,24)]
    new_matrices[i].append(a)
```